# NodeJS - image conversion in base 64 results inverted collors using pdf-image, bluebird, hi-base64, gm and image-magic

Tags: node.js, base64, imagemagick, bluebird, image-manipulation

I have this code bellow its receive an base64 pdf and convert to jpg image in base64 too...Its runs in master environment but in dev the generated picture came with inverted collors (like negative picture).
The package.json libs is the same in both branches:

```
"appdynamics": "^4.4.3",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"bluebird": "3.3.4",
"body-parser": "1.10.2",
"express": "^4.11.1",
"fs-extra": "4.0.0",
"gm": "1.23.0",
"goo.gl": "0.1.4",
"hi-base64": "0.2.1",
"package.json": "^2.0.1",
"pdf-image": "1.1.0",
"pdf2json": "1.1.7",
"request": "^2.88.0",
"request-promise": "^4.2.2",
"simple-node-logger": "^0.93.37",
"uuid-v4": "0.1.0"
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
var PDFImage = require("pdf-image").PDFImage;
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var base64 = require('hi-base64');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

function writeFile(base64data, uuid) {
    return new bluebird.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var pdfFile = __dirname + "/" + uuid + ".pdf";
        var bytes = base64.decode.bytes(base64data.toString());

        var buffer = new Buffer(bytes.length);
        for (var i = 0;i < bytes.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = bytes[i];
        }

        fs.createWriteStream(pdfFile).write(buffer);
        fs.close;
        resolve({
            "pdfFile": pdfFile, 
            "uuid": uuid
        });
    });
}

function convertToJpg(file, uuid) {
    return new bluebird.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var pdfImage = new PDFImage(file);
        pdfImage.setConvertOptions({
            '-density': '300',
            '-depth': '8',
            '-background': 'white',
            '-flatten': '',
            '-quality': '70',
            '-resize': '50%'
        });
        pdfImage.setConvertExtension("jpg");
        pdfImage.convertPage(0).then(function(imagePath) {
            resolve({
                jpgFile: imagePath, 
                uuid: uuid
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}

function readFile(file, uuid) {
    return new bluebird.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({
                    data: data, 
                    uuid: uuid
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

function deleteFiles(data, uuid) {
    return new bluebird.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.unlink(__dirname + "/" + uuid + ".pdf", function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
        fs.unlink(__dirname + "/" + uuid + "-0.jpg", function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
        resolve({
            data: data,
            uuid: uuid
        });
    });
}

var api = {
    getJpg: function(req, res, next) {
        log.info("[getJpgService] URL requested.: " + req.headers.host); 
        var uuidv4 = require('uuid-v4');
        
        log.info("[getJpgService] Getting base64 data ...");       
        var base64data = req.body.bytesBoleto;
        var uuid = uuidv4();

        log.info("[getJpgService] Writing PDF file");
        writeFile(base64data, uuid).then(function(writeResult) {
            log.info("[getJpgService] Converting to Jpg");
            convertToJpg(writeResult.pdfFile, writeResult.uuid).then(function(convertResult) {
                log.info("[getJpgService] Reading Jpg file");
                readFile(convertResult.jpgFile, convertResult.uuid).then(function(readResult) {
                    log.info("[getJpgService] Deleting temp file");
                    deleteFiles(readResult.data, readResult.uuid).then(function(deleteResult) {
                        res.contentType("image/jpg");
                        res.status(200).send(deleteResult.data);
                    });
                    log.info("[getJpgService] Boleto Jpg generated.");
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                res.status(500).send(error);
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = api;
```

1- I've tried do install ghostscript in docker file running this command line:

```
RUN yum install -y gcc ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ghostscript
```

2- and change some versions of libs, but produces the same effect

I don't understand node very well but I have to fix this issue...someone have any idea?

Comment: If it was originally CMYK colorspace, then it might view as inverted colors.

Comment: I solved this using '-colorspace': 'RGB' in setConvertOptions !  Thanks @fmw42

Comment: You probably want sRGB not RGB. RGB is linear and will give darker results. sRGB is non-linear and the usual colorspace and should be normal brighter result.